# How to access from Web App (loaded using inAppBrowser) the local Ionic App assets?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

I have a web app that is being loaded from an Ionic App using inAppBrowser. I'm trying to access a local file from the assets folder of the Ionic App and load that to the web app. Is this possible?

Here's a diagram of what I want to do:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: Any luck in achieving this?

Comment: Nope, no luck...